# How to upload file using easy-ftp in node?

Tags: node.js, sftp

I am trying to upload a file into my hosting server using node and easy-ftp.

I try with the following code:

```
var EasyFtp = require ("easy-ftp");
var ftp = new EasyFtp();

var config = {

    host:'homexxxxx.1and1-data.host',
    type:'SFTP',
    port:'22',
    username:'u90xxxx',
    password:"mypass"
};
ftp.connect(config);
ftp.upload("/test/test.txt", "/test.txt", function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
    ftp.close();
});
```

No error message but no file uploaded

I tried the same using promises

```
const EasyFTP = require('easy-ftp-extra')
const ftp = new EasyFTP()
const config = {
        host:'homexxxxx.1and1-data.host',
        type:'SFTP',
        port:'22',
        username:'u90xxxx',
        password:"mypass"
    };
ftp.connect(config);

ftp.upload('/test.txt', '/test.txt')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
ftp.upload()
```

The same issued. No file is uploaded. No error in node console.

The config is the same used in filezilla to transfer files. SFTP protocol. Everything working well with filezilla.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: or, may anybody advice a different node package to do this stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have a path problem over here.

**"/test/test.txt"**

The path specified will try to take file from root folder like "c:\test\test.txt".

Assuming you want the file to be taken from your project folder try this path:
"./test/test.txt"

Other things in your code are precisely the same as in mine and mine works.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was just silently failing, and intelli-sense was not available.

- `npm remove easy-ftp`
- `npm install easy-ftp`
- `npm audit fix --force` until no more vulnerabilities

Afterwards, intelli-sense was available and it started working.